# React-Native (Android) : Request failed with status code 403 - bscscan api testnet

Tags: android, react-native, axios, http-status-code-403, bscscan

Please help me, I'm so stuck on this problem: I'm making an request BSCSCAN-API-TESTNET with Axios on React Native and the request is working correctly only within the iOS, but it is not working with the Android (403 Forbidden response).

My URL request: https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x400ee0c820144c8bb559ace1ad75e5c13e750334&sort=desc&apikey=P3A263376TPJHKQ5IXUD4VHUNFQKDJB4G5
I updated the apiKey so don't mind it.

My code: (IOS: oke, android: throw error 403)

```js
try {
  const url =
    'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x400ee0c820144c8bb559ace1ad75e5c13e750334&sort=desc&apikey=P3A263376TPJHKQ5IXUD4VHUNFQKDJB4G5';
  const response = await axios.get(url);
} catch (error) {
  throw error;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the **user agent** helped me solve the 403 issue.

```
try {
      const url =
        'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x400ee0c820144c8bb559ace1ad75e5c13e750334&sort=desc&apikey=P3A263376TPJHKQ5IXUD4VHUNFQKDJB4G5';
      const response = await axios.get(url, {headers: { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0" }});
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Man.. your answer saved my sanity! But do you know why this help?